# What does adding between dimensions mean if anything at all? Are there useful conventions for doing so?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, matrix-rank, octave

[Conceptually](http://www.3blue1brown.com), why is adding a scalar to a matrix defined ins some cases when adding matrices of different dimensions does not seem to make sense?  What does it mean to add a dot to a line, or a line to a square, or a square to a cube, or a dot or line or square to a cube?
An answer in words is  fine.  I tried the following and am still having trouble picturing what is going on.

Note: *This question is NOT about the mechanics of Octave.  It is about understanding the space of what adding between dimensions means if it means anything at all.  By example Octave defined its own way described below, and Feynman defined his own math a child.  Are there any useful conventions in adding between dimensions, and if so, what are they and why are they useful?*

An answer on this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1379252) suggests implicitly using the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) to add a scalar to a matrix.  However [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) and [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) do not behave that way.  Instead they behave as if adding a scalar to a matrix is like multiplying a matrix of all ones by the scalar and then adding that result to the original matrix.

By example Octave lets you add the scalar, 1, to a matrix of different size even though it treats a scalar as a matrix of size 1x1.  Notice how the results for A+1 and A+eye(2) differ and how A+eye(3) fails.

```
octave:1> A=eye(2)
A =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0
   0   1

octave:2> A+1
ans =

   2   1
   1   2

octave:3> A+eye(2)
ans =

Diagonal Matrix

   2   0
   0   2

octave:4> A+eye(3)
error: operator +: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x2, op2 is 3x3)
octave:4> size(1)
ans =

   1   1
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25576104) suggests that *trailing singleton dimensions do not count*.  Meaning

```
octave:5> A(2,1,1)
ans = 0
```

Given that why does A+eye(3) fail?  What does A(2,1,1) mean for a 2x2 matrix?

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1095245) suggests when adding vectors of different dimensions of the shorter vector could be padded with zeros in undefined dimensions.  It then talks about some kind of infinite vector space which I am having trouble picturing.  It suggests something like the following is possible even though it seems nonsensical to me.  And, as expected, it does not work in Octave.

```
octave:6> A(1,1)=eye(2)
error: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 2x2)
```

Comment: Programmers choose what they choose. Perhaps they consulted mathematicians and deemed it a shortcut worth having.

Comment: What you cited about treating scalar $s$ as a matrix $sI$ is indeed, possibly, the only correct way to use, as $(sI)\mathbf v = s\mathbf v$ for any vector $\mathbf v$ in any vector space—this is a pretty natural property, and $I$ here could only be the identity operator (or matrix, in case of $\mathbb R^n$ spaces), you can even prove that easily.

Comment: This convention of an implicit “for each” goes back at least as far as APL.

Comment: Programmers added this because sometimes matrices are not interpreted as linear transformations but as data arrays, and it's often useful to be able to add or subtract a constant from all data points. Mathematicians don't allow this because it doesn't satisfy the standard properties that linear algebra is built on, e.g. $(A+s)B \ne AB+sB$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is a bit nuanced. In mathematics you can define whatever you want. Georg Cantor wrote (in German) "The essence of mathematics lies entirely in its freedom." So, for example, you **could** define the addition of any two matrices of any size. Same thing holds in defining any programming language. The pragmatic questions are "What is the point of the definition? What kind of purposes can it be used for? What useful properties does it have? Does it lead to any ontradictions?" This freedom allows that there can be many different possible definitions of something, and some of them may be equivalent to other definitions, but do not have to be, and that can lead to ambiguities and confusion. What usually happens is that a lot of decisions are made for convenience reasons, particularly in programming languages which are less constrained than pure mathematics.

For the particular questions that you asked, it seems to be that the designers of the programming languages you mentioned thought it would be convenient to design the operations the way they did. It need **not** be consistent with more conventional mathematical choices as long as they are being **documented** clearly. Perhaps in time, the abuse of notation $A-\lambda$ instead of $A-\lambda I$ will win.

Comment: Are you saying math is what we agree to define it to be in the context in which we use it?  I suppose the questions I asked were something like "what is 3 + a square?", or "what is a square + a cube?"  I suppose they don't make sense.  Yet Feynman defined his own math as a child.  He changed later in life when he realized nobody else could understand what he was talking about.  Is there any already established convention in this space of adding between dimensions?

Comment: @SpeedCoder5: You understand my point well. Yes, Feynman defined his own math, and so can anyone with the problems that would entail. As far as established convention, no, but MATLAB and Mathematica are popular and you **can** add scalars to vectors/matrices in them because it is useful.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a scalar to a matrix isn’t defined.

Octave is interpreting the “scalar” as the scalar times the all-ones matrix of the correct size.

Comment: You claim that 'adding a scalar to a matrix isn't defined'. Isn't it strange that 'multiplying a scalar to a matrix' is defined? To me, it would make more sense if you replace "the scalar times the all-ones matrix of the correct size" by "the matrix of the correct size with all entries equal to the scalar value" or something similar.

Comment: @EdG Not at all. Matrices are vectors, and so scalar multiplication is defined but scalar addition isn’t just like I can’t add $7$ to $(7,1)$. And just like in that case I can interpret $7+(7,1)$ to mean $(7,7)+(7,1)$.

Comment: I guess I'm messing things up. I was just thinking that if you see a scalar as a $1$-by-$1$ matrix, it doesn't make sense to multiply is by a, let say, $2$-by-$3$ matrix, though in practice we often multiply scalars with matrices, so what you say makes sense. Nevertheless, I have difficulty with understanding 'matrices are vectors'. For me a vector one dimensional thing while a matrix is a higher dimensional thing but I guess I miss some basic knowledge on this subject

Comment: @EdG The dimension of a vector is the number of locational slots t has. $(1,2)\in\mathbb R^2$ is 2-dimensional and $(1,2,3,4,5)\in\mathbb R^5$ is 5-dimensional. We can likewise say that an $n\times m$ matrix is $nm$ dimensional. In fact, the set of matrices of dimension $n\times m$ with coefficients in $F$ satisfies the vector space axioms and is isomorphic to $F^{nm}$! This vector space is denoted $M_{n\times m}(F)$

Comment: A scalar can be thought of as a $1\times 1$ matrix in the sense that by the above, $M_{1\times 1}(F)\cong F$, but in many other contexts (such as the current context) that’s misleading. If you are interested in learning more about this, Wikipedia’s article on vector spaces is quite good for people not familiar with the topic.